# Customizing DecimalRow Text Color

Tags: eureka-forms

I am trying to change the text color of DecimalRow. Neither the tintColor nor textColor attributes on cell.textField seem to do anything:

```
<<< DecimalRow(){
    $0.tag = "final";
    $0.useFormatterDuringInput = true
    let formatter = CurrencyFormatter()
    formatter.locale = .current
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    $0.formatter = formatter
    }.cellSetup({ (cell, row) in
        cell.textField.textColor = UIColor(red:0.15, green:0.55, blue:0.16, alpha:1.0)
        cell.textField.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.15, green:0.55, blue:0.16, alpha:1.0)
    })
```

Comment: Hello my answer solve your problem?, can you let me know about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `cellUpdate` closure instead, it works, look at the picture below

```
        <<< DecimalRow(){
            $0.tag = "final";
            $0.useFormatterDuringInput = true
            let formatter = CurrencyFormatter()
            formatter.locale = .current
            formatter.numberStyle = .currency
            $0.formatter = formatter
            }.cellUpdate({ (cell, row) in
                cell.textField.textColor = UIColor(red:0.15, green:0.55, blue:0.16, alpha:1.0)
                cell.textField.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.15, green:0.55, blue:0.16, alpha:1.0)
            })
```

[image]

I hope this helps you, best regards